# isolated scope function with parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a table with switch toggle in it. When i toggle a switch function should run for that particular row.  for toggle i used [angular-toggle-switch](https://github.com/cgarvis/angular-toggle-switch).  To achieve this i need the row's id and toggle value.

View

```
<tr rec-status ng-repeat='staff in staffs | filter:query | orderBy: sort.field : sort.order'>
    <td ng-repeat='field in fields'>
        {{staff[field]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <toggle-switch selid="{{staff.id}}" clickhandle="changeStatus()" ng-model="switchStatus" on-label="Active" off-label="Inactive">
        <toggle-switch>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Directive for Toggle-switch

```
scope: {
  disabled: '@',
  onLabel: '@',
  offLabel: '@',
  knobLabel: '@',
  selid:'@',
  clickhandle:'&',
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
  if (!attrs.onLabel) { attrs.onLabel = 'On'; }
  if (!attrs.offLabel) { attrs.offLabel = 'Off'; }
  if (!attrs.knobLabel) { attrs.knobLabel = '\u00a0'; }
  if (!attrs.disabled) { attrs.disabled = false; }

  element.on('click', function(e) {
    scope.$apply(scope.toggle);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
     return modelValue;
  });

  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
    return viewValue;
  });

  ngModelCtrl.$render = function(){
      scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
  };

  scope.toggle = function toggle(e) {
    if(!scope.disabled) {
      scope.model = !scope.model;
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.model);
      data = {};
      data['value'] = scope.model;
      data['id'] = attrs.selid;
      scope.clickhandle(data);
    }
  };
}
```

controller

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

I am getting **undefined** as output.

but if i use `scope.clickhandle({value:"true"});` its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an object of arguments into the function call as per your `scope.clickhandle({value:"true"});` example is the correct way to be calling functions defined with `&` in an isolate scope. As per the docs, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#scope

> ...the isolate scope property will point to a *function wrapper*...
>
> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22})

Comment: can you fiddle or plunker with expression wrapper fn?

Comment: what is missing that you would like to see in a fiddle? In your code, you can inspect the `scope.clickhandle` and see that it is not actually the function that you passed in using the `clickhandle` attribute, but a function that Angular creates - this is the wrapper function.